# Идея не видит Switch

Tags: java, switch

Прописываю в идее эллементарный код со свитчем. Но мне идея выдает,что она якобы не видит метод Switch. Cannot resolve method Switch (int). Но мне то метод и не нужен...только оператор множественного выбора Switch со всеми своими кейсам и брейками)

Comment: Так оператор множественного выбора пишется с маленькой буквы - `switch`.

Comment: Спасибо. На эллементарном попалась.

Answer (score 3):

Тут без кода можно гадать, но самое примитивное : switch или Switch пишете?

Comment: Спасибо) уже поняла. Java регистрозависимый.. и switch с маленькой буквы)